# What does the [analysis] tag mean?

Tags: discussion, status-deferred, tags, disambiguation

I just reviewed a tag wiki written for the [analysis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analysis) tag and it seemed like it would have been more suited to a tag named [spatial-analysis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spatial-analysis).  Nevertheless, in the absence of a better classification/definition, I approved it.

A quick review of a few of the 128 or so Questions tagged [analysis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analysis) suggests to me  that this tag is often being used in in the same way I would use the [geoprocessing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geoprocessing) tag e.g. [What is the FME Equivalent to the ArcGIS Union tool?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79938/what-is-the-fme-equivalent-to-the-arcgis-union-tool).

Should [analysis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analysis) and the not yet used [spatial-analysis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spatial-analysis) tags simply be made synonyms of [geoprocessing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geoprocessing) as a "quick fix", or should the [analysis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analysis) tag be disambiguated in a way that will take considerably more effort along the lines of what was done [here](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3388/how-to-disambiguate-the-adf-tag) for [adf](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adf)?

Personally, I am hoping for a [A real solution to ambiguous tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125234/a-real-solution-to-ambiguous-tags) to be implemented.

Comment: Isn't geoprocessing broader than spatial-analysis? Also, not all processing that is done with geographical data can be considered an analysis. For example: changing a projection or a color of a map. I believe they should not be synonyms, but +1 for bringing up this subject.

Comment: I believe that "geoprocessing" is also, like "analysis", too broad a tag to useful on this site.

Comment: @martinf I think that depends on how the geoprocessing tag is written - it could exclusively refer to the Geoprocessing Framework of the ArcGIS Platform and have some value but I do not know if the term is used widely outside of ArcGIS.

Comment: @martif I agree with @PolyGeo on this. If you look at the questions tagged `geoprocessing` there are only a handful which do not deal with the esri geoprocessing framework. Maybe the community (after discussion) can look into changing the tag wiki to represent this general understanding.

Comment: Ah! I've known of the term "geoprocessing" since the late 1970s: it was the name of an academic journal, edited by Tom Poiker (formerly Peucker), on any aspect of digital geographic ("geospatial" had not been proposed then) data processing. I did not even know it had been co-opted by Esri. However, given that Esri is the Microsoft of GIS, it doesn't surprise me...

Comment: So, is it safe to assume that what we decide for "analysis", needing disambiguation, also applies to "geoproessing"? Or do we need a separate "vote"?

Comment: @martinf I'm inclined to see whether we can work on disambiguating `geoprocessing` first, as a separate Question to see what consensus there is, and then come back to `analysis` and `spatial analysis`.

Comment: @PolyGeo - I hear you -- even if you got it the wrong way round. :-)

Comment: See [**here**](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3480/should-geoprocessing-tag-be-used-only-for-geoprocessing-framework-of-arcgis) for `geoprocessing` tag discussion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I feel that the [analysis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analysis) tag is far too generic and ambiguous.

While GIS deals with a Spatial analysis to a great extent, it's not the only analysis that we do. We also do Temporal analysis, Statistical analysis, and some even do Business/Commercial analysis.

If you look at the questions tagged analysis, I feel that most of them are using the tag in a generic sense, not just limited to Spatial Analysis.

Comment: I suggest people vote for this Answer if they favour disambiguation over simple synonymizing.

Comment: Rather than down voting this Answer, or possibly as well as, I would suggest someone who favours synonymizing should write another Answer proposing that as the best way forward.

Answer (score 1):

Both [analysis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analysis) and [geoprocessing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geoprocessing) tags should be burninated (eliminated), because they are acting like meta tags within our site, i.e., they are not helping to identify and search content.

---

<sub>On the other hand, tags [geoprocessing-framework](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geoprocessing-framework) (for ArcGIS) and [qgis-processing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-processing) are useful because they identify a particular subset of questions specific to internal tools/framework on both software.</sub>

Comment: I think burninating the [tag:analysis] tag is the easier and higher priority of the two, but that [tag:geoprocessing] should be disambiguated to [tag:geoprocessing-framework] and [tag:qgis-processing], and then burninated soon after that.  I think we may already have enough consensus to commence burninating (removing/replacing) the [tag:analysis] tag from questions.

Comment: Perhaps, a first action would be to edit the tag excerpts as an attempt to avoid new questions with them. But I think we would need more votes on this answer to carry on (at least regarding "geoprocessing"). @PolyGeo.