# Should [geoprocessing] tag be used only for Geoprocessing Framework of ArcGIS?

Tags: discussion, status-deferred, tags, disambiguation

This Question arises from a **[Question about the `analysis` tag](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3463/what-does-the-analysis-tag-mean)**.  There I suggested that [analysis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analysis) and [geoprocessing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geoprocessing) are used here in a way that could possibly lead to them being synonyms.  This led to discussion about whether [analysis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analysis) is actually broader than [geoprocessing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geoprocessing), or *vice versa*.

At the moment our **[tag wiki for `geoprocessing`](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geoprocessing)** says:

> Geoprocessing is a GIS operation used to manipulate GIS data.
>
> "... A typical geoprocessing operation takes an input dataset,
>   performs an operation on that dataset, and returns the result of the
>   operation as an output dataset. Common geoprocessing operations
>   include geographic feature overlay, feature selection and analysis,
>   topology processing, raster processing, and data conversion."
>   --Wikipedia

Perhaps we can start to make some headway by either editing the **[tag wiki for `geoprocessing`](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geoprocessing)** to make it equivalent to the Geoprocessing Framework of ArcGIS or coin a new tag of [geoprocessing-framework](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geoprocessing-framework) to do that.  I suspect that if we do the latter the former tag will probably be used any way and so I am inclined not to coin the new tag.

Would you be happy/OK to have [geoprocessing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geoprocessing) represent only questions about the Geoprocessing Framework of ArcGIS?  If so, we can then return to disambiguating the remainder of what currently gets tagged as `analysis`/`geoprocessing`.

Personally, I am hoping for a [A real solution to ambiguous tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125234/a-real-solution-to-ambiguous-tags) to be implemented.

Comment: While Geoprocessing sounds quite vendor neutral, I've never heard it being used without it being a reference to ESRI's framework. I don't know whether this is just a result of the kind of people I deal with, or whether this is an Industry-wide practice. Maybe those who work exclusively on software other than ESRI, might be in a better position to throw some light on this.

Comment: One Answer to this [**Question**](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80376/how-to-select-inverse-of-intersection-of-two-polygon-layers) has a picture of a QGIS menu that suggests the term Geoprocessing term is used there but in a much narrower sense than in ArcGIS.

Comment: I always assumed it was much narrower simply because QGIS hasn't (yet) implemented a full suite of such tools. :-) Your evidence is clear, however: "geoprocessing" has been appropriated as a term of art outside the ESRI sphere and thereby attains a generic meaning that ought to be reflected in our use of the [tag:geoprocessing] tag.

Comment: I've known of the term Geoprocessing since the late 1970s: it was the name of an academic journal, edited by Tom Poiker (formerly Peucker), on any aspect of digital geographic data processing. (The term "geospatial" had not been proposed back then.) It ran for about 10 years. I did not even know "geoprocessing" was being used by Esri in a narrow sense, and strongly object to words/terms having their meaning changed, even if inadvertently, by large organizations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [geoprocessing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geoprocessing) is a general term which is not exclusive to ESRI software at all.

Therefore I would welcome a new [geoprocessing-framework](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geoprocessing-framework) tag which would be ESRI-specific.

Similarly, I would support renaming [processing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/processing) which currently describes the QGIS "Processing" (formerly Sextante) plugin to [qgis-processing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-processing).

Comment: I've known of the term _Geoprocessing_ since the late 1970s: it was the name of an academic journal, edited by Tom Poiker (formerly Peucker), on any aspect of digital geographic data processing.  (The term "geospatial" had not been proposed back then.) It ran for about 10 years.  I did not even know "geoprocessing" was being used by Esri in a narrow sense, and _strongly object_ to words/terms having their meaning changed, even if inadvertently, by large organizations.

Comment: I agree - and discussion at http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3373/should-we-introduce-a-new-tag-for-qgis-sextant suggests the community might be more or less behind you on the `qgis-processing` tag idea.

Answer (score 1):

I went looking through the tags, and we already have [processing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/processing) which is specifically for the Processing toolbox in QGIS:

> Spatial data processing framework that brings advanced analysis capabilities to QGIS.

I would normally say that geoprocessing is a general term and it should apply to concept no matter which application is in use, but it's already been separated out for QGIS. So it may be more appropriate to alter the [geoprocessing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geoprocessing) tag to be ArcGIS specific.